# how to keep only 11 length by line in notepad?

Tags: notepad++, notepad, notepad2

for exemple, there will be a list like this one:

```
12345678901:1020
12345678902:1030563
```

I'd like to keep it like this format:

```
12345678901
12345678902
```

basically, 11 digits by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^(.{1,11}).*$
Replace: $1
```

### Demo